# objectcontext disposed exception

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Each user have a function (student, developer, actor ...), so each user in Users had int attribute which is a foreign key in Functions, and each function have multiple name in each culture, so Functions had int attribute which is a foreign key in Functions_Translations, this where I have the name of the function in each Culture

In my contoller :

```
        Users user = new Users();
        using (var db = new MyAppContext())
        {
            user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mail == "tester@test.test");
        }
        return View(user );
```

In my view :

```
@model Models.Users
...
@Model.Functions.Functions_Translations.Select( x => x.FunctionId == Model.FunctionId  & x.CultureId == 1).First()... (don't know how do show the attribute Name in Functions_Translations )
```

I have 2 questions : 
How to display the Name attribute in Functions_Translation and the second and the most important :

In the view i get the folowing error : The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I saw a lot of solution like doing :

```
make user var and do return view(user.tolist())
```

but that force me to do foreach in my view. Is there another solution ?

Sorry for my english and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please set the following and try it once.

`db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled= false;`

Use this line as the first line inside the `using` block and then do the rest of the other operations. And for the first question, please clarify by providing properties of the `Functions_Translations` model and also explain what you are trying to accomplish.